# Store custom HTML elements in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to allow users to add customizable `HTML` elements. However, no `HTML` will be required, just settings. For example, if the user wants to create a button, only the name, and href will be required. A similar approach will be with links, images, and etc.

I don't know how to store these values in the database. The first thing that came to my mind was to create tables like: `buttons`, `links`, etc, with columns: `href`, `name`, and so on. Unfortunately, I am not sure if this is the right way since I'll have options like `border-radius` or `padding` in the tables as well. Besides, I am not sure if this is practical because in production it will lead to some performance issues.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Thank you!